# Apache redirection of subdomain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, virtualhost

I have a subdomain (called subdomain.mydomain.com)

I just want that a page (ex: www.mydomain.com/page1.php) redirects to my subdomain

So when i load subdomain.mydomain.com i want to go to www.mydomain.com/page1.php but conserving my subdomain in the url

Using htacess or virtualhost

here is my edited code with your comments

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)com=who(&|$) [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.mysite\.fr$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^index\.php/?$ http://apropos.mysite.fr/? [NC,L,R]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^apropos\.mysite\.fr$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ http://www.mysite.fr/index.php?com=who [L,P,QSA]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try following code in your ROOT .htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on

# Redirects www.mydomain.com/page1.php?com=who to subdomain.mydomain.com
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)com=who(&|$) [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.mydomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^page\.php/?$ http://subdomain.mydomain.com/? [NC,L,R]

# Internal Redirect(Proxy) subdomain.mydomain.com to www.mydomain.com/page1.php?com=who
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain\.mydomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ http://www.mydomain.com/page.php?com=who [L,P,QSA]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i think it will be work
but i made a mistake in my request, the redirected page is not page1.php but page1.php?com=who
i think it will change the correct code ?

Comment: I edited my question to show you the code
because the redirection tells me : Not Found - The requested URL /index was not found on this server.
My subdomain have no virtualhost
When i select http://www.mysite.fr/index.php?com=who i go to apropos.mysite.fr but with the error message

Comment: I think you have a typo in your last RewriteRule. Can you remove last `?` after `?com=who` and try again. Once that is done when you visit `http://apropos.mysite.fr/` in your browser pls see what happens?

Comment: That's weird. Can you comment out first rule completely (2 RewriteCond lines and 1 RewriteRule line) and then visit the same URL `http://apropos.mysite.fr/`. If that also doesn't work try changing flag `P` to `R`.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7049/discussion-between-bklups-and-anubhava)

Answer (score 1):

> So when i load subdomain.mydomain.com i want to go to www.mydomain.com/page1.php but conserving my subdomain in the url

Try putting the following in the .htaccess in the root directory of you site. I am assuming that your subdomain and domain share the same root.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

# page (ex: www.mydomain.com/page1.php) redirects to my subdomain
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.mydomain\.com$ [NC]
#do not redirect if from proxy
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(^|&)r=1(&|$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^page1\.php/?$ http://subdomain.mydomain.com [NC,L,R=301]


#if subdomain.mydomain.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain\.mydomain\.com$ [NC]
#and root directory, then proxy to page1
RewriteRule ^$ http://www.mydomain.com/page1.php?r=1 [P,L]
```

Comment: I edited my code, the last 2 lignes work but the 3 of the beginning not
when i go to http://www.mysite.fr/index.php?com=who or another pages i want to stay on http://subdomain.mysite.fr